# Magento2.2.2 - After installing fresh instance with sample data product page returns 404

Tags: magento2, product, category, 404-page

I have installed fresh **magento 2.2.2** instance with sample data. After hitting all required commands as a guest I can not see any single product on category listing page and product page returns 404.But after login as a customer I can see product listing on category page and able to access product page.

Please suggest what is the issue.

Comment: Is your magento instance in developer mode? What did your logs says?

Comment: clear pub/static/frontend folder and reload

Comment: @lpFranz I have checked log I found this: [2018-03-09 06:06:11] report.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000; Allocated memory size: 100000000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size: 134217728 bytes.

Comment: @aravind already clear content and redeploy it again.

Comment: have a look at this doc 
    http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611304/how-can-i-limit-the-size-of-temporary-tables